# Angular iFrame and Reverse Proxy

Tags: angular, iframe, reverse-proxy

I have one dashboard application which runs on a specific port.

Angular app runs on different port.

As per some documentation, I have used the proxy.

Here is what I have in proxy.conf.json file

```
{
  "/apik/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8123/dashboard",
    "secure": false
 }
}
```

In the ts file, I'm setting up the URL as

```
url = 'apik/'
```

In the HTML file, I'm opening the dashboard using iFrame as follows

```
<iframe [src]="url" style="width: 100%;height: 500;border: none;"></iframe>
```

But I'm getting following error

```
ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

I tried using the sanitizer in HTML as follows

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)" style="width: 100%;height: 500;border: none;"></iframe>
```

But this opens same page twice.

I'm running the code using following

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Is this correct?

Could you please help?

Comment: Where you able to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public url: string;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
   this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('apik/');
}
```

and then ...

```
<iframe [src]="url" style="width: 100%;height: 500;border: none;"></iframe>
```